# How to approach team member that constantly asks partner questions?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

I am a leader of a team of four within a Development office that encompasses a support/triage role for juniors and help desk staff.

Of my team there is one who's partner also works in the same office. This person is smart but unsuited to their role and does wish to transition into another which there is no headcount for but still tries to take pride in their work. One issue I've noticed is that they'll often ask their partner questions about their work and their partner will essentially do the work for them, the other half of their work they'll ask me questions about and it can be quite frustrating that they know the answer and don't know I know they ask their partner questions all day too.

It's not stuff that they shouldn't and don't know. They seem to just be very afraid to be wrong on something so never trust their gut.

Another frustrating thing they'll do is ask me something which I'll let them know how it's done, how to investigate something where something is held in the database etc. Then 5 minutes later I'll get "X thinks it's done like this" to which I sometimes answer unfortunately quite shortly with something along the lines of "well do that then", which is obviously not constructive.

I'm not sure how to handle this in a way without sounding petty or that I don't value them as a team member because I do.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Are you a manager in the situation? Please [edit] your question to clarify.  If you're not a manager, rest assured the managers know about the problem.

Comment: Why is the fact that the person is their significant other relevant here? Why do you feel there is a conflict of interest? What outcome do you want? (Please edit)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this team member simply lacks confidence in their solutions and is simply looking for reassurance before proceeding with their task.

One way to help them build confidence in their solution is to simple ask them the same questions that they constantly ask you. "Hey XX. I need you to do Y. What do you think the best way to do Y is?". This puts them on the spot, forces them to reply to you and if you confirm that their answer is correct, will help give them a small confidence boost.

If their answer is wrong, simply ask another question to help them over come any issues they may have overlooked "You recommended W, but because of V it won't work. Do you have any ideas for a work around?". Just make sure to semi step in and provide suggestions if you see that they are actually stuck and in a bind.

You also mention that they sometimes ask someone else for an alternative solution and send it back to you. You should take a short time to explain the differences between the proposed solution. This should help them build up enough knowledge to figure out that different solutions can achieve the same results and allow them to identify the one that they are most comfortable with.

Repeat this enough times and they will start to trust their own solutions and ideas instead of trying to find the best and one that wont get them into trouble.

Comment: Good answer: One other thing: treat your colleagues in a way that's blind to the relationships between them. Make every effort to avoid getting triangulated -- caught in the middle between two people with an existing relationship.

Answer (score 2):

> It's not stuff that they shouldn't and don't know. They seem to just
>   be very afraid to be wrong on something so never trust thier gut.
>
> I'm not sure how to handle this in a way without sounding petty or
>   that I don't value them as a team member because I do.
>
> How should I approach this?

In my experience, the key is to make the employee feel that they are safe making mistakes.

I usually try something like "Well, what do you think?" then tell them to go with their answer. And I try to point out that everyone makes mistakes, and that it's more important to make progress than never make a mistake.

When their gut is right, I congratulate them on their insight and try to suggest that they should feel okay about going with what they feel is right. But then you must never criticize an incorrect choice. It's okay to to suggest an alternative while still support their choice.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy you could use is when you give them a task, ask them if they've been shown how to do it. Or if it was a while ago, ask if they remember how. If they're at all unsure, ask them to write up a short procedure, set of guide lines or proposed plan. It should include any questions.

Then you can check it, fix any mistakes, answer any questions and assure them that it's what you want.

This doesn't have to be fancy, text documents on a shared folder are fine.

The idea is that you get to give them regular good feedback that they can do the job before they have to take the risk of doing the wrong thing, and they never have the unpleasant experience of making a mistake that causes a problem.

Also, for repeat jobs, they can just refer to their previous notes, and the next new guy will have a set of procedures to learn from.

Answer (score -2):

Do everything you can to emphasize that there is more than one correct way to do things, which is likely one of the roots of this lack of confidence. When they grasp this, they will not continually search for a singular solution.

Also, if X says this is the way to do it, simply say that is one way of doing it among others.